# Axios interceptor that relies on context state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-context

I have a function component that handles some of my axios interceptors. However there is a request interceptor that I cannot get working. This interceptor relies on a piece of my auth context and when that context changes, I need the interceptor to see this value change and attach it to the request. I've tried this multiple ways and I can't get it to work correctly.

Attempt 1:
The problem with this attempt is the cleanup function keeps firing on state change and its removing the interceptor. The interceptor never works and is not attaching the account_id to request.

```
const { accounts } = useAuth(); // context
...
useEffect(() => {
  const interceptor = api.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      if (accounts.active) {
        config.params = config.params || {};
        config.params['user_account_id'] = accounts.active;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

  return () => { api.interceptors.request.eject(interceptor) };
}, [accounts.active]);
```

Attempt 2: The problem with this attempt is that the value for `accounts.active` is stale because I'm not passing it as a dependency. The interceptor works but again just with a stale state value.

```
const { accounts } = useAuth(); // context
...
useEffect(() => {
  const interceptor = api.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      if (accounts.active) {
        config.params = config.params || {};
        config.params['user_account_id'] = accounts.active;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

  return () => { api.interceptors.request.eject(interceptor) };
}, [ ]);
```

Attempt 3: The problem with this attempt is that it's attaching multiple instances an interceptor because there is no cleanup function. The interceptor is firing however its firing multiple times with some of those being stale context values.

```
const { accounts } = useAuth(); // context
...
useEffect(() => {
  const interceptor = api.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      if (accounts.active) {
        config.params = config.params || {};
        config.params['user_account_id'] = accounts.active;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );
}, [accounts.active]);
```

Pretty much what I am trying to accomplish here is this: Send `account_id` with every single request, that `account_id` can change at any time and the most up to date `account_id` in the state is the one that must be passed with each request.

Comment: I think the attempt 1 should work. When the dep changes, the cleanup function will be called first, then the setup function. You need to send the HTTP request after the interceptor is added.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this in the future the problem was the useEffect closure issue. The only way I was able to get around this is to use a ref.

```
const { accounts } = useAuth(); // context
const accountRef = useRef(null); // ref
...
useEffect(() => {
  accountRef.current = facebookAccounts.active; // <-- Use a reference
  const interceptor = api.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      if (accountRef.current) {
        config.params = config.params || {};
        config.params['user_account_id'] = accountRef.current;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

}, [accounts.active]);
```